# Hot reload crashing after changing sub-file of "folder import"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, es6-modules

I have a project setup that looks like this (use this as an MVCE):

```
src/
  styles/
    index.ts
    common.ts
  app.tsx
```

The code in `index.js` looks like this:

```
import CommonStyles from "./common.ts";
export { CommonStyles };
```

`common.ts` looks like this:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const CommonStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    example: {
        width: "50%",
        height: "50%",
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }
});
export default CommonStyles;
```

From `app.tsx` i import these styles like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { CommonStyles } from "./styles";

function App() {
    return (
        <View style={CommonStyles.example} />
    );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that, when I change the style in `common.ts` (e.g. `width: "75%"`) then save it, the app crashes with this error:

> Requiring module `"src\styles\index.ts"`, which threw an exception: `TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.`

#### Versions

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1   

"react": "16.8.6"
"react-native": "0.60.5"
```

I am not using expo.

*P.S. I don't know what the JS term for "folder importing" like this is so feel free to edit title, thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded versions to react native `0.61.0` which fixes this bug. For anyone that is stuck on lower versions of react native there are a few workarounds you can try:

## Rename imports

Apparently renaming imports is one solution:

```
import CS from "./common.ts";
const CommonStyles = CS;
export { CommonStyles };
```

## Enable loose mode

Adding this to your `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` should also work:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
      {
        strictMode: false,
        allowTopLevelThis: true,
        loose: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```